# Find contours of same color pixels in an image in Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV. I am just wondering does OpenCV have function to find contours of same color pixels automatically. Currently, the only idea I can come up with is that do the binary transformation for certain color first, then use cv2.findContours(). Any better ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: @Piglet Hi, thank you for the link, but I think they are highlighting the relative location instead of circling the real contours.